# unable to get correct using strtotime("2015-02-14") function in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I want timestamp of date that I use in strtotime() function. But it gives me timestamp of day before that date. 
Suppose if I use:

```
echo strtotime("2015-02-14");
```

then it give me `1423868400` this, which is timestamp of "`2015-02-13`".

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe is a problem with the `timezone`. You can set your `timezone` as follow:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo strtotime("2015-02-14"); // Shows 1423872000
```

**EDIT:**

```
// With your timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo strtotime("2015-02-14"); // Shows 1423852200
```

You can read more about `date_default_timezone_set` method here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

And also more about `strtotime` method also here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Exact ! For a list of the timezones you can use, check the link below, you should find yours... 

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a timezone issue here. By giving a date without any hour, it assumes you're saying 0h0min0sec... whether the server is before or after greenwich might change the final result ;)

Try to [setTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.settimezone.php) to your working current time zone before issuing your script, that could be the solution.

Comment: I have already used settimezone in following code. date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

Comment: As wrote tomloprod in his latest edit : 

`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

echo strtotime("2015-02-14"); // Shows 1423852200

// then

echo date("Y-m-d",1423852200); // Shows 2015-02-14 `


There should be no issues so far…